# Importing File to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a comma delimited file which I want to import into SQL Server.

The file is quite huge (240MB).

I need to import the same via the following process:

1. Create table to import to.
2. The first line of the file would correspond to the column of the table.
3. All items would be treated as string.

Is there a tool in SQL server specifically designed to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into [bulk import:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx)

Comment: If you have SQL Server Management Studio you can use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, set the data source to Flat File Source and then you can browse for your file and set the options you need like specifying the columns. This wizard is available in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 I am not sure about earlier versions. You can find the wizard by right click your database select Tasks > Import Data...

Comment: I have SQL Server Management Studio but the Import data facility parses the first line as a row in the table. I need the first line to denote as the column names in the table.

Comment: IF you look at te first scren that you get when you choose flat file source, after you pick a file location you can check "Column Names in the first data Row" and then it will use them as column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard,

- Set the Data Source to Flat File Source
- Browse your CSV File
- Check the check box "Column names in the first data row"
- Check out the preview to see if that's the result you want.

Good luck.

Comment: To elaborate, the SQL Server Import/Export wizard will help you do this.  It will also allow you the option of saving as an SSIS pacakge which you can schedule in a sql job step.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a one-off file, then use what used to be called DTS, now commonly referred to as the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard.

BCP is probably a bit more complicated to set up and get going for a one-off file, but if you're doing this often, then learn and use BCP.

In the Import/Export wizard there is a checkbox on the Choosa a Data Source screen, at the General tab called 'Column names in the first data row'; that will let you have the first row as a header row.

treating all items as string is fine, Import/Export wizard sets columns to string by default, with a width of 50, so you might want to increase it slightly if your data is going to be wider than that.